# different size of images coco dataset

Tags: image-resizing, coco

I load coco dataset then I use transform to resize images for creating dataloader.
But I face 2 errors
error 1 : RuntimeError: Trying to resize storage that is not resizable
error 2 : RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [3, 480, 640] at entry 0 and [3, 500, 500] at entry 1

I think resize transform can not be applied to images.

Does anybody know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

First error indicates there are some issues with your dataset. Take a look at your dataset. Try load samples one by one and check if there are some corrupted images.

The second error seems that is thrown from pytorch dataloader. The error is obvious by itself. As suggested [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/runtimeerror-stack-expects-each-tensor-to-be-equal-size-but-got-3-224-224-at-entry-0-and-3-224-336-at-entry-3/87211/10?u=mohammad_hassan_soha), try to use `transforms.Resize` like this: `transforms.Resize((img_size, img_size))`